# iPad sticky menu not functioning

Tags: jquery, css, ipad

I have a sticky menu that only works on desktop computers, but not on an iPad or mobile device.  When I scroll on the iPad the menu disappears instead of remaining at the top of the page.

Here's my [demo](http://www.benergywebsitedesign.com/get_started.htm).

```
**tmstickup.js**

(function($,undefined){
    var 
        def={
            stuckClass:'isStuck'            
        }
        ,doc=$(document)

    $.fn.TMStickUp=function(opt){
        opt=$.extend(true,{},def,opt)

        $(this).each(function(){
            var $this=$(this)
                ,posY//=$this.offset().top+$this.outerHeight()
                ,isStuck=false
                ,clone=$this.clone().appendTo($this.parent()).addClass(opt.stuckClass)
                ,height//=$this.outerHeight()
                ,stuckedHeight=clone.outerHeight()
                ,opened//=$.cookie&&$.cookie('panel1')==='opened'
                ,tmr

            $(window).resize(function(){
                clearTimeout(tmr)               
                clone.css({top:isStuck?0:-stuckedHeight,visibility:isStuck?'visible':'hidden'})
                tmr=setTimeout(function(){
                    posY=$this.offset().top//+$this.outerHeight()               
                    height=$this.outerHeight()
                    stuckedHeight=clone.outerHeight()
                    opened=$.cookie&&$.cookie('panel1')==='opened'

                    clone.css({top:isStuck?0:-stuckedHeight})
                },40)
            }).resize()

            clone.css({
                position:'fixed'                
                ,width:'100%'
            })

            $this
                .on('rePosition',function(e,d){
                    if(isStuck)
                        clone.animate({marginTop:d},{easing:'linear'})
                    if(d===0)
                        opened=false
                    else
                        opened=true
                })

            doc
                .on('scroll',function(){
                    var scrollTop=doc.scrollTop()

                    if(scrollTop>=posY&&!isStuck){                      
                        clone
                            .stop()
                            .css({visibility:'visible'})
                            .animate({
                                top:0
                                ,marginTop:opened?50:0
                            },{

                            })

                        isStuck=true
                    }

                    if(scrollTop<posY+height&&isStuck){
                        $('.js-search').removeClass('active');
                        clone
                            .stop()
                            .animate({
                                top:-stuckedHeight
                                ,marginTop:0
                            },{
                                duration:200
                                ,complete:function(){
                                    clone.css({visibility:'hidden'})
                                }
                            })

                        isStuck=false
                    }           
                })              
                .trigger('scroll')
        })
    }
})(jQuery)

**script.js**

include('js/tmstickup.js');
$(window).load(function () {
    if ($('html').hasClass('desktop')) {
        $('#stuck_container').TMStickUp({
        })
    }
});

**style.css**

.stuck_container {
  padding: 40px 0 43px;
  background: #0fcabf;
  background-image:url('../images/graph.png')
}

.isStuck {
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 20px 0 23px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.isStuck .sf-menu > li > ul {
  top: 39px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .isStuck {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your media query forcefully tells to hide 'isStuck' div below 767px i.e. for ipad and mobile devices . If you want sticky menu to work on on an iPad or mobile device. Simply remove media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .isStuck {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Bhagya
Thanks, but that didn't work.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: @MonteOrganics I have not tested  on actual device but even if I decrease browser widow below 767px issue was there and that was due to media query , removing media query fixed it on browser ..

Comment: @MonteOrganics I think you have removed media query from your demo page and it is working flawless when you decrease browser window below 767px. If it is device specific problem then need to debug it on device.. But for sure it is styling issue..

Comment: It was never an issue on the pc browsers, just on mobile devices.  I removed it anyway, but it doesn't seem to have made a difference.  If you test on a mobile device and come up with a work-a-round please let me know, ok?  I'd be happy to comp you if you wish!  Thanks.